# Hide UITableView search bar by default when in a navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've read multiple posts on this but it's not working properly for me. I'm using the latest 4.2 SDK.

The code I have is

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 44.0);
```

This partially works, it moves the search bar up a little bit, but it does not get hidden completely. I've tried increasing the value 44 to something greater and this had no affect what so ever! I'm calling this code in the viewDidLoad method of the table's view controller. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain how you laid your tableview out?

Comment: I'd check out `wantsFullScreenLayout`.  If you have a bar at the bottom that will cover part of the table you could either add a footerview 44px high (quick and easy) or you could drop the tableview into a parentview (bit more work but cleaner).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 44.0);
```

The above code does in fact work but it needs to run after the UITableView has finished creating all of its cells. I guess thats another question though.

Comment: how did you make sure the tableview has finished creating all the cells? Can you give me some clues? Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Another approach should be...in viewDidLoad call:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame.size.height, 0, 0, 0);
```

and implementing endDragging delegate method:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    CGPoint offset = self.tableView.contentOffset;

    CGFloat barHeight = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame.size.height;
    if (offset.y <= barHeight/2.0f) {
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    } else {
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-barHeight, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    self.tableView.contentOffset = offset;
}
```

setting content is to remove some "flickering"

also if You want searchbar to stick at the top, implement didScroll this way:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
     CGRect sbFrame = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame;
     sbFrame.origin.y = self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
     if (sbFrame.origin.y > 0) {
         sbFrame.origin.y = 0;
     }
     self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame = sbFrame;
}
```

I hope this will help (took me few days to figure out:) )

Cheers!

UPDATE:

As @carbonr noted You should add this line in viewDidLoad since iOS7+

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Comment: Thanks! It was exactly the "set content offset to remove flickering" part I was missing.

Comment: @GrizzlyNetch thanks a ton !!!! awesome solution, I had been struggling for a long time. What this solution also does is that when the user taps on the top of the iPhone (outside of the app), the  table view scrolls to the top but hides the scroll bar, unless he pulls it down after that.

Comment: @GrizzlyNetch I have a doubt, inside scrollViewDidEndDragging implementation we need to check if the table view being scrolled is self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView or self.tableView.

Comment: @user1046037 good point for optimisation, but i think it will work this way either. But for sure it is better to check which table has been dragged.

Comment: The code will behave unexpectedly on iOS 7 and to fix that you need to add this to your `viewDidLoad`. This is new a API `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`

Answer (score 4):

You can set the initial bounds of the table view inside `viewDidLoad`, so the search bar appears hidden at the beginning.

You have to create the `searchBar` property and then use following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //...
    CGRect bounds = self.tableView.bounds;
    bounds.origin.y = self.tableView.bounds.origin.y + searchBar.bounds.size.height;
    self.tableView.bounds = bounds;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For others still looking for an updated solution, you can check out my answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35282000/130556).

Basically you need to update the `contentOffset` the first time `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called.

Answer (score -1):

I also have the same problem like yours. The following code solved my problem.Please add the code in you viewDidLoad() :

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

N:B: I used autoLayout in my project.