# UITableView offset hiding section header

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

On my app I have setup a UISearchBar that is initially offset until the user scrolls up. The problem is that the section headers (letters on the right hand side) are also offset, thus hiding the first two letters.

How can I remove the offset for this only or remove it altogether?

Comment: Did you add "UISearchBar" as tableHeaderView?

Comment: I just dragged it in from Xcode. How do i add it as a tableHeaderView? Also the offset code was found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272923/hide-uitableview-search-bar-by-default-when-in-a-navigation-controller