# Set UITableView content inset permanently

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, pull-to-refresh

In my app I have a `UISearchBar` under `UINavigationBar` so it is always visible to user. In that case I had to set `contentInset` with extra 44px so the `UIScrollView` will be scrolling under `UISearchBar` **(exactly like in Contacts.app)**. And there would be no problem with static `UITableView`'s but in my case I have to reload it's contents, switch to `UISearchDisplayController`etc. So when I call:

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(108, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Everything works until e.g. I pull to refresh... (for this I use `SSPullToRefresh`).

So my question is: **How can I set `contentInset` permanently so I wouldn't have to worry about any changes happening to data inside `UITableView`?**

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Probably it was some sort of my mistake because of me messing with autolayouts and storyboard but I found an answer.

You have to take care of this little guy in **View Controller's** Attribute Inspector
[image: asvi]

It must be unchecked so the default `contentInset` wouldn't be set after any change.
After that it is just adding one-liner to `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(108, 0, 0, 0)]; // 108 is only example
```

---

**iOS 11, Xcode 9 update**

Looks like the previous solution is no longer a correct one if it comes to **iOS 11** and **Xcode 9**. `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` has been deprecated and right now to achieve similar effect you have to go to **Size Inspector** where you can find this:
[image]
Also, you can achieve the same in code:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Comment: Genius! I think this "little guy" should be unchecked by default. Now what are in the storyboard (uitableview&uiscrollview) match what I have  in my iPhone.

Comment: This has been bugging me for months, but not enough to look it up. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! When "little guy" is checked, SB toys with contentInsets at viewDidLayoutSubviews (between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear).

Comment: What is equivalent in Swift 2.3?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey shouldn't be much difference...
`self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(108, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: what does "this little guy" refer to?  EDITED:Adjust Scroll View Insets. I had to download the image to see that

Comment: @WilliamGP it's "Adjust Scroll View Insets" chexkmark in Attributes Inspector 

Comment: It was enough to set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `.never` - no need to change the "Adjust Scroll View Insets".

Answer (score 95):

In Swift:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
      super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
      self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 108, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

Comment: Why not calling `super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()` ?

Comment: There is no need for it because the default implementation of viewDidLayoutSubviews does nothing.  (Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews )

Comment: That's true Johanneke.  It is best practice to call super, in case of architecture changes in your own application or changes to UIKit by Apple.

Answer (score 11):

automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets is deprecated in iOS11 (and the accepted solution no longer works). use:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to be able to tie contentInsets to selected safe area (ie not all)

Answer (score 6):

Add in numberOfRowsInSection your code `[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(108, 0, 0, 0)];`. So you will set your contentInset always you reload data in your table

Comment: This doesn't work. When I pull to refresh content inset is being restored to factory settings.

Comment: Maybe try moving that line to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: You can add your searchbar as header of your table too like this `[tableView setTableHeaderView:yourSearchBar];`

Comment: But the search bar must be always visible to user. Nevermind, I've found solution. Read my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is how it can be fixed easily through Storyboard (iOS 11 and Xcode 9.1):

Select Table View > Size Inspector > Content Insets: Never

Answer (score 2):

After one hour of tests the only way that works 100% is this one:

```
-(void)hideSearchBar
{
    if([self.tableSearchBar.text length]<=0 && !self.tableSearchBar.isFirstResponder)
    {
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.tableSearchBar.bounds.size.height);
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeBottom;
    }
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [self hideSearchBar];
}
```

with this approach you can always hide the search bar if is empty

Answer (score 0):

Try setting tableFooterView
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude))

Answer (score -3):

```
      self.rx.viewDidAppearOnce
            .flatMapLatest { _ in RxKeyboard.instance.isHidden }
            .bind(onNext: { [unowned self] isHidden in
                guard !isHidden else { return }
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .automatic
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
            })
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```