# UITableView ContentInset and ContentOffset

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I'm having trouble with the `contentInset` property. I have a `UITableView`, with dynamic cell sizes (AutoLayout). I'm setting the `contentInset` property to leave some space above the top of the content. But I'm getting the following result:

[image: Unexpected Result]

The content is in blue, the content inset in purple. When the table view first appears, it is in the left situation. I can scroll to get to the right situation, that is working, but I would like the table view to appears directly as in the right illustration — which I thought would be the default behavior.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020943/set-uitableview-content-inset-permanently

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I saw that already and tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best way but I fixed it by adding:

```
tableView.contentOffset.y = -70
```

after the line:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 70, left: 0, bottom: 50, right: 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can scroll programmatically when the view loads.

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -70), animated: false)
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, not very pretty though. I thought the scrollview would automatically adjust so that it's scrolled "to the top" directly

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be fixed easily from the Storyboard:

Table View > Size Inspector > Content Insets: Never

Comment: I'm not using Storyboard, but I tried using scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior, it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You provide an UIEdgeInset object,

```
UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

The top property shows the distance from top of content to top border of the area.

Comment: yeah this is what I'm doing