# Hiding a toolbar element when UITableView scrolls (similar to Facebook's app?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

How I can achieve this effect?

[image: full top view]
 [image: half top view]
 
[image: top view almost hidden]

Comment: Which part of the screenshots shows the effect you want? Is it the Status, Photo, etc?

Comment: Oh, you'll need to using the scrollview delegate methods to do this. It's just a UIView that sits above the table view.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This isn't immediately noticeable from your screenshots, but I believe you want the that header toolbar to slide up as the user scrolls, right? (I'd suggest clarifying on that part)

You can do this a few ways, and in all of them you will have to implement your own scrolling logic, meaning how much the header toolbar slides up depending on where you have scrolled. That said, here's how to do it:

**1**. If you're using `UITableView`, I assume you've got your view controller set as its `delegate`. Since `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` already, just add the [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) to your view controller. That will give us scroll events as they happen. You'll want to do your logic in [`scrollViewDidScroll:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll:).

**2.**. If you're simply using `UIScrollView`, just set your view controller as its delegate, implement [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html), and do your logic in [`scrollViewDidScroll:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll:).

That said, your code might look something like this:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint scrollPos = scrollView.contentOffset;

    if(scrollPos.y >= 40 /* or CGRectGetHeight(yourToolbar.frame) */){
        // Fully hide your toolbar
    } else {
        // Slide it up incrementally, etc.
    }
}
```

Anyway, hope I helped.

Answer (score 6):

If you have properly set the delegate, your table will call scrollViewDidScroll: when scrolled.

So in your controller, you can add something like :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >0)    //means that the user began to scroll down the table
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
            //animations you want to perform
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here i implemented code for UIView Hide / Show when tableview scrolling. When tableview scrolling down then UIView is hidden and when scrolling up then UIView show. I hope it's working for you...!

Step 1:- Make one property in .h file

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat previousContentOffset;
```

Step 2:- Write down this code in scrollViewDidScroll Method.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

CGFloat currentContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

if (currentContentOffset > self.previousContentOffset) {
    // scrolling towards the bottom
    [self.subButtonView setHidden:YES];
} else if (currentContentOffset < self.previousContentOffset) {
    // scrolling towards the top
    [self.subButtonView setHidden:NO];
}
self.previousContentOffset = currentContentOffset; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I create simple class for this effect: 
[UIHidingView is an iOS class that displays UIView element on top UITableView which is hiding when Table View is scrolling.](https://github.com/yoman07/UIHidingView)

Comment: It is working fine. but, this category holds a big issue.
After add this category. when we try to present gallery by using UIImagePickerController, we can't view photos in albums in ios6.

Answer (score 0):

This will answer your question :

[iPhone: Hide UITableView search bar by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081381/iphone-hide-uitableview-search-bar-by-default)

same concept, different control. You can put a UIView on top row of tableview or any other relevant control such as button.

Good luck.