# Adding a view on top of a UITableViewController that is initially hidden until the user pulls down

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I want to add a search on top of a UITableViewController, but I want the field to be hidden initially (like Notes app) until the user pulls down to reveal it. How can I achieve this?

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9632860/2629258

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `UITableView`'s `tableHeaderView`. When done in code, it looks like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.tableView.bounds.origin.x, self.tableView.bounds.origin.y,     self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 44.0)];
    self.mySearchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    self.mySearchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.mySearchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.mySearchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tableview searchbar with the searchbar delegate.

On the viewDidLoad method you can manually scroll up the tableview. You can set an IBOulet on the searchbar to access its frame's height to know its height.