# Hide UITableView search bar by default

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

I Know this is a repeated question, but I have tried all searched answers,

such as:
[iPhone: Hide UITableView search bar by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081381/iphone-hide-uitableview-search-bar-by-default/9632860#9632860)

but when i try this:

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44)];
```

there's a flicker on the top(Navigation's position) when push to this viewcontroller.

because at the begin, my tablecell number is 0, so I cannot use this:

```
[yourTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a flicker because you don't have enough rows to fill the content size of the tableView, and iOS will adjust the inset automatically in this situation.

The `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` method doesn't work in this case, either.

The only solution I got so far is inserting enough empty cells to the tableView. By doing so, the content size is big enough, and iOS won't set the inset.

Here is a [Swift example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31084998/938380). Although it's in Swift, the idea is the same. You can translate it into Objective-C easily.