# How to show/hide UISearchBar by action in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have a `UITableView` with a `UISearchBar`. I need to show/hide my `searchBar`, by user action (button pressing):

I tried to use this code:

```
if self.tableView.contentOffset.y == 0 {
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: self.searchBar.frame.size.height) 
}
```

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081381/iphone-hide-uitableview-search-bar-by-default) question.
Actually I've tried all of those answers. All of them just scroll my `UITableView`, and each time I'm scrolling my `UITableView` - `searchBar` appears.
I tried to do something like this:

```
self.newsTableView.tableHeaderView = nil; //Hide
```

and

```
self.newsTableView.tableHeaderView = self.SearchBar; //Show
```

But `UITableView` doesn't want to return `searchBar`;

How can I resolve this problem?
I need to hide `searchBar` by action, not to scroll my `UITableView` (hide like `searchBar.hidden = true`) Actually, `searchBar.hidden = true` works, but there is a white space instead of `searchBar`.

Comment: Does the TableView hide the search abr correctly when you try                            `self.newsTableView.tableHeaderView = nil`?

Comment: Yes It works fine. It hides, and there is no white spaces instead of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use UIView.animation for searchBar and tableView
When you start scroll table
Change position/alpha of search bar and height of tableView

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
          searchBar.alpha = 0.0
          tableView.view.frame.height = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)
                    }, completion: {
                        (value: Bool) in
                        //do nothing after animation
                })
```

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 7.3 in the ViewController.swift file it worked properly for me

```
CategoryTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar // show

CategoryTableView.tableHeaderView = nil // hide
searchController.active = false
```

Answer (score 1):

hope this could solve your problem. call this at launch of tableview to hide the searchBar and when you scroll down it will appear

```
var newBounds: CGRect? = self.newsTableView.bounds
    newBounds?.origin.y = 0
    newBounds?.origin.y = newBounds!.origin.y + self.searchBar.bounds.size.height
```

and then set the new bound of the tableView