# IOS: Scrollable search bar similar to Mail or Messages apps

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

New iOS developer here! I love the design of scrolling up to a hidden search bar. I want to duplicate it but a lot of the solutions seem outdated, so i am really confused.

[iPhone: Hide UITableView search bar by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081381/iphone-hide-uitableview-search-bar-by-default)

Going off of this, it seems like there's 2 steps.

1. Add search bar to the scrollable table view
2. Add code so it scrolls to the second row on app load (in viewdidload?) using

   `yourTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)`

I can't get passed #1. I tried putting in a search bar in 3 spots...

[image]

- A) If I put it here (on top of the header?) it sticks at the top as expected, but not scrollable.
- B) If I put it here, it's still not scrollable and it blocks the first row
- C) If I put it here, it repeats on the row, as expected.

Somehow I need to put it on the table without duplicating, so I'm confused on that.

Comment: Took down my answer as the original you referenced explains this very well. Put your search bar in the header view of your table. Then scroll to the top row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you have to do this in code. If you want to do it, I followed the tutorial here and it worked.

http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift

Add UISearchResultsUpdating

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
```

Add these properties...

```
let tableData = ["One","Two","Three","Twenty-One", "vasdf", "vasdfd", "3343", "ad23", "454d", "vasdf32", "va343", "vasdf3r2", "vasdfd2", "vasr52f", "awefwr32vwf"]
var filteredTableData = [String]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
```

Add self.resultSearchController here...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()

    // Reload the table
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Take care of self.resultSearchController.active conditions in these functions...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // 2
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        return self.filteredTableData.count
    }
    else {
        return self.tableData.count
    }
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

    // 3
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Then do the search code here

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text as String!)
    let array = (tableData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And I think that's it. Good luck!